# What is wrong with this AngularJS directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, imgix

I am trying to write a imgix directive for AngularJS. Here is my code:

```
MetronicApp
.directive('imgix', function() {
    return {
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            url: '='
        },
        restrict: "A",
        template: "<img class='thumbnail inline' width={{w}} height={{h}} src='https://mysite.imgix.net/{{url}}?h={{h}}&w={{w}}&fit=crop'>",
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
            function ctrl(value, mode) {
                // check inputs
                if ((value === null) || (value === undefined) || (value === '')) {
                    // let's do nothing if the value comes in empty, null or undefined
                    return;
                }

                scope.h = attrs.height || 50;
                scope.w = attrs.width || 50;
                scope.url = value;


            }

            // by default the values will come in as undefined so we need to setup a
            // watch to notify us when the value changes
            scope.$watch(attrs.url, function(value) {
                ctrl(value, 'url');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And in html, I have 2 images:

```
 <img imgix data-height="200" data-width="200" url="theme.options.homepageBackground" />

 <img imgix data-height="200" data-width="200" url="theme.options.menuBackground" />
```

But the result is like in the picture:

[image]

I didn't understand what is wrong. Is there something about scope?

Comment: What is your problem ?

Comment: Despite two image urls are exactly different, both of them show the same image.

Comment: is `theme.options.homepageBackground` an angular var ? If yes, you've to change by `{{ theme.options.homepageBackground }}`

Comment: They are angular variables. But images are not shown now.

Comment: Forget what I said, I double checked and it's wrong. You had the right syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your directive scope is bound to the parent scope. Either use a child or isolated scope instead.

`MetronicApp.directive('imgix', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            url: '='
        }`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using ng-src attribute and passing the whole url from your link function to the directive.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue with the combination of Matthias and Julien

First, I added curly brackets to the directive:

```
<imgix data-height="200" data-width="200" url="{{theme.options.menuBackground}}" />
```

Then I added scope: {} to the directive code

And I saw that value in watch code returns undefined. I changed with that:

```
scope.$watch(attrs.url, function(value) {
                ctrl(attrs.url, 'url');
            });
```

Now it works. Thank you.